# Wordpress: How to get the date by URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, archive

I want to make it quick:
how can I get rid of the month?
Im using a simple the_date('F Y') in the archives.php-template, but I need to make it relative to the path/level of the archive.

PLZ look at the attached picture!

[image]

Comment: `the_date('Y')`

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_month, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_year - take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

`the_date('Y')` will give you just the year. Presumably, Wordpress is using the standard date formatting options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: But Wordpress uses only one template-file, no matter which level you're in. Therefore I need a script, which checks the current level and generates either ('Y') or ('F Y').

Comment: @Tim, then please post the code where this page is generated. There must be some parameter you can use to either display "Y" or "F Y"